# Using GO in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am working on SQL Server 2005 and I have come accros the issue that I have run the multiple update query on the single table one by one. As it takes lots of time to execute one by one I came to know that by using "GO" I can run the query one by one. Like this

```
Update Table A ....
```

GO

Update Table A

GO

Update Table A

I am not sure that I can put seperate update statement like this and it will run the query one by one. As I doing it on production I need to be sure that it should work.

Can anyone give me an example where I can see that by using GO, query runs one by one and not parallel?

Comment: If you are not sure about them ,then run each update separately..

Comment: Thanks Srini but I have several update statement and most of them are on the same table. and they take different time to execute so I thought to make a sequencial run instead of waiting and doing it manual one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [GO (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx)

> **GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the
>   sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL
>   Server Management Studio Code
>   editor.**
>
> SQL Server utilities interpret GO as a
>   signal that they should send the
>   current batch of Transact-SQL
>   statements to an instance of SQL
>   Server. The current batch of
>   statements is composed of all
>   statements entered since the last GO,
>   or since the start of the ad hoc
>   session or script if this is the first
>   GO.

Comment: As I am using SQL Server management studio, does it means that it will execute these update statement seperately ?

Comment: @Andrew Barber, please be aware that GO is an SSMS command, not TSQL, as I stated. So I think the best would be to get GO out of your mind entirely if you can X-)

Answer (score 2):

Your queries will not be run in parallel whether or not you use the `GO` command. astander posted an answer explaining what `GO` is. Read that, then come back here.

Regardless whether you use the `GO` command, your script will be run one-statement-after-another. They are not run in parallel.

You can prove this by writing a script such as this (pseudo code, but you get the idea)

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ([id], [data]) VALUES (3, 'I am here')
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE [id]=3
```

You can put a `GO` between those statements or not, the result will be the same: the first command will -always- fully complete before the second one is run.